# Integer values in a defined range for simulated data

Tags: r, simulation, survey, structural-equation-modeling

I am trying to simulate survey data based on output from structural equation modeling (SEM) using the "simsem" package in R. Because each variable represents a question in a survey I would like the resulting data set to only contain integers, between e.g. 1 - 5.

Is there a way to do this within the "simsem" package or is there another package more suited for this? I have been thinking that I could assign the integer values after the simulation. E.g. lowest 15% = 1 next 20% = 2 etc reflecting the frequency given by the real data (suggestions to do this in a good way would be appreciated).

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I choose to solve my problem like this. First i simulated my data following this [tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/simulating-data-following-a-given-covariance-structure/) .

To assign the integer values per the original frequency distrobution i did the following:

```
a1_cut <- quantile(rdata$a1, c(.10, .32, .71, .80)) 
rdata$int_a1[(rdata$a1 <= a1_cut[1])] <- 1
rdata$int_a1[(rdata$a1 > a1_cut[1]) & (rdata$a1 <= a1_cut[2])] <- 2
rdata$int_a1[(rdata$a1 > a1_cut[2]) & (rdata$a1 <= a1_cut[3])] <- 3
rdata$int_a1[(rdata$a1 > a1_cut[3]) & (rdata$a1 <= a1_cut[4])] <- 4
rdata$int_a1[(rdata$a > a1_cut[4])] <- 5
```

Any opinions on this way to solve it would be great.